# Unexpected token import when using custom transformer of babel-jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

When I run `npm test` (`jest --watch`), I get:

```
C:\sites\YDR\branches\trunk\development\app\static\js\_modules\marketplace\postbacks\Components\Form.js:44
import('Form').then(function (m) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/postbacks-form.js:1:115)
```

Jest's part of package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": "./../../",
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>tools/webpack/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>development/app/static/css/_modules/",
      "<rootDir>development/app/static/js/_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/tools/webpack/jest.transform.js"
    }
  }
```

jest.transform.js:

```
// Custom Jest transform implementation that wraps babel-jest and injects our
// babel presets, so we don't have to use .babelrc.
module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer({
    presets: [
        require("babel-preset-react"),
        require("babel-preset-es2015")
    ],
    plugins: [
        require("babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"),
    ]
});
```

I'm using following versions:

- node@8.1.3
- npm@5.3.0
- jest@20.0.4
- babel-core@6.25.0
- babel-jest@20.0.3
- babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@6.18.0

I've also tried babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node@1.0.2, but then I have different error:

```
Plugin 0 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "default"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It's a [bug](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node/issues/27) within babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node.

Can be work around by adding `.default` to require:

```
module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer({
    presets: [
        require("babel-preset-react"),
        require("babel-preset-es2015")
    ],

    plugins: [
        require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"),
        require("babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node").default,
    ]
});
```

Also, in order to be able to parse `import()`, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs is needed.

Comment: why is it required to use `require("babel-preset-react"),` and not simply `"babel-preset-react"` ?